# Create folder with special characters in truecrypt on fedora 20

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, truecrypt, utf-8

I have a problem to create folders and files containing special characters (eg é, è , ù , ç .... )

Volume:
Volume Type : Normal
Size: 10M
Encryption : AES
Hash : RIPEMD -160
File System : FAT

I ride my volume without problems and I can create folders and files without special characters ( accents )

Fedora 20

root # locale

> LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
>   LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
>   LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
>   LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
>   LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
>   LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_ALL=

root # locale-a | grep fr

> fran�ais fr_BE fr_BE@euro fr_BE.iso88591 fr_BE.iso885915@euro
>   fr_BE.utf8 fr_CA fr_CA.iso88591 fr_CA.utf8 fr_CH fr_CH.iso88591
>   fr_CH.utf8 french fr_FR fr_FR@euro fr_FR.iso88591 fr_FR.iso885915@euro
>   fr_FR.utf8 fr_LU fr_LU@euro fr_LU.iso88591 fr_LU.iso885915@euro
>   fr_LU.utf8

I currently have an Ubuntu seveur containing truecrypt volume and it's not a problem

Comment: I do not think FAT filesystem can properly handle special characters.

Comment: I create a volume EXT2 to test, actually accents are no longer a problem so I think switch to FAT => EXT4

Answer (score 0):

If it's FAT you are trying on then what you are trying to do is not allowed,
You will get the allowed characterset in filename [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)

Please change the type of filesystem if its a desperate requirement